# Нужно нарисовать прямоугольник из "*" используя две петли For

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
rows = random.randint(1,5)
colomns = random.randint(1,5)
print(rows)
print(colomns)
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(colomns):
        print("*", end='')
```

Почему этот вариант не рисует прямоугольник а просто умножает количество звезд rows и colomns в ряд?

Comment: Надо в конце цикла по х добавить print('\n'), или просто print()

Comment: Или print(end='n')

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример рисования заполненного прямоугольника

```
import random
rows = random.randint(1,5)
cols = random.randint(1,5)

print(rows)
print(cols)
for x in range(rows):
    for y in range(cols):
        print("*", end='')
    print()
```

Вот пример рисования пустого прямоугольника

```
import random
rows = random.randint(1,5)
cols = random.randint(1,5)

print(rows)
print(cols)
for x in range(rows):
    if x==0 or x==rows-1:
        for y in range(cols):
            print("*", end='')
    if x>=1 and x<=rows-2:
        for y in range(cols):
            if y==0 or y==cols-1:
                print("*", end='')
            if y>=1 and y<=cols-2:
                print(" ", end='')
    print("")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам, а можете, пожалуйста обьяснить зачем нужно писать print() в последней строчке вашего первого кода? Этого я не пойму

Comment: Мы выводим символы в строку. Последний принт переводит курсор на следующую строку. Это не последняя строка кода, а последняя в теле цикла.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

А почему должен быть не ряд звездочек?
Так задан у вас алгоритм задачи - рисование в ряд(печать задана во внутреннем цикле). И рандомные значения для количества рядов/колонок тут не очень наглядны.

Переделал вашу программку в более удобоваримый вид:

```
#import random
#rows = random.randint(1,5)
#colomns = random.randint(1,5)
#print(rows)
#print(colomns)
rows=7
colomns=15
sim=" "
for x in range(rows):
    if x==0 or x==rows-1 :
        sim="*"
        for y in range(colomns):
            if y==colomns-1:
                print(sim, "\t")
            else :
                print(sim, end='')
    else :
        sim=" "
        print("*", end='')
        for y in range(colomns-2):
            print(sim, end='')
        print("*", "\t")
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за помощь, но мне тяжело понять ваш код и это усложнение (if, else) зачем оно?

Comment: if проверяет, является ли строка первой или последней.Если "да", то рисует сплошную звездочками. если нет, то идет формирование строки слева и справа которой звездочки, а внутри заполнена пробелами. Поэтому и range(colomns-2) как раз за минусом крайних позиций.
P.S. А "\t"  для перевода каретки, т.е. для завершения одной строки и перехода печати на следующую.